# Bubble sort recurrence formula

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I wrote the following recursive version of Bubble sort Algorithm:

```
fun Bubb(A,i,j):
if (j = 1) then
    {return A[j]}
if (A[i] > A[i+1]) then
    {swap A[i] and A[i+1]}
Bubb(A,i+1,j)
Bubb(A,i,j+1)
```

Although I know Bubble sort takes *`O(n^2)`* time in the worst case. I am not sure if my the following recurrence formula is really correct:

```
T(n) = T(n)T(n-1) + O(1)
```

Since we compare two elements at each time, we say `T(n)T(n-1)` plus a constant time taken for swap operation.

Can someone verify if my understanding is correct?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How did you derive this result? Maybe if you explain how you got it you'll be able to either spot a hole in your understanding or convince yourself that you're correct.

Comment: I will modify the question

Comment: Always a good idea to enclose the code to be executed inside `{}` so you know what the `if` goes on. In other words `if <condition> {stuff-to-be-done}` is easier to read.

Comment: Your code will keep calling Bubb(A, i, j) for ever-increasing values of $i$. So it doesn't terminate and you can't usefully analyse its time complexity.